# krunner - like solution in non kde environment

Tags: unity, kde, unity-dash, tracker, krunner

Good evening everyone. I am currently running KDE on my laptop and I would like to know if there is something with the same capabilities of krunner for unity DE. What I really need is a good file index capability plus application control, just like krunner. I know the dash can look similar but due to Zeitgeist it does not is useful to me, and moreover it is damn slower than krunner. I tried also tracker search service in unity, but it is not at all integrated with the dash. I also know that gnome 3.12+ includes tracker search provider in search queries but I do not like really much the environment. Please not answer me something like: "why not you stuck with KDE?"

Much thanks in advance.

Marco

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to try [Gnome Do](http://do.cooperteam.net/). It is fully customizable with plugins and you can also choose which folders you want to index, the depth of indexing and which folders or subfolders you want to ignore.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer

Comment: @UserName I edited it, it should be ok now